# Unanswered questions with just comments

Tags: discussion

I'm looking through a lot of the unanswered questions and it appears some of them have answers in the comments. So what is the solution for these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 options that I see

1. Ask the commenter to add the comment as an answer
2. Add the comment as an answer, and assign to community wiki
3. Add the comment as your own answer, and try to grab a couple of rep points for yourself
4. Ignore it, and continue on

Comment: Note that for both 2 and 3 you should give credit to the commenter for the content which is theirs, and should probably prefer 2 over 3 unless you are adding more than just what was in the comment.  If you are adding more detail/examples/etc. then getting rep for that is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: And note that just adding the comment as an answer might be a risky thing to do. You have to make sure it's a good answer. Which in most cases will mean at least some editing is needed. Comments rarely make good answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could leave a comment, asking the author to make it an answer.

If that results in nothing, and if you can construct a good answer based on the information in the comments, by all means go ahead. Keep in mind though that comments don't always make for good answers. So try to avoid merely copying the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are mean to clarify question and give suggestion for answer, but it does not mean that it is correct answer.

If it's comment, than user who commented might be not sure with answer.

Also, SO have restriction for comment, so all new users cannot comment..

But anytime user who has questioned can ask the user who commented to put it as answer and mark it as correct answer and mark it correct.